# [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: npm, vue.js, persian-calendar

I want to use an npm module which is based on Vue:

[Persian Date & Time Picker For Vue.js](http://www.vuescript.com/persian-date-time-picker-vue-js/)

because I'm not familiar with node.js, I used **wzrd.in** to get a `window.vuePersianDatetimePicker` object:

https://wzrd.in/standalone/vue-persian-datetime-picker@latest

I used it in my code(I only include contents of my body tag):

```
<div id="app">       
    <date-picker></date-picker>
</div>


<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script src='https://wzrd.in/standalone/vue-persian-datetime-picker@latest'></script>
<script>
    Vue.component('date-picker',vuePersianDatetimePicker)
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        });
</script>
```

but I cannot use it and get the following error:

[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the contents of `vuePersianDatetimePicker` object and found the solution.

I should have used `vuePersianDatetimePicker.default` instead of `vuePersianDatetimePicker`

Comment: you save my day!